# How to decrease size of class in DDD to not break the encapsulation?

Tags: java, refactoring, domain-driven-design

**I'm trying to understand the DDD** and I'm encountering some problems. Now I'm refactoring some of domain class N. It has a lot of methods that takes a DTO, validates it and then updates some fields of N. I feel that further it will have much more methods. I think that it's good to preventively extract methods from the N to own classes, a.k.a. Commands. But it means that this commands will have the access to fields of N. Will this refactoring break encapsulation? Is there a way to decrease N's size more safe?

**This is what I have**

```java
class N {

  // Other fields

  private String someField;

  // Other fields

  public void editSomeField(SomeFieldEditCommand command) {
    // Some validations
    this.someField = command.getSomeField();
  }
  
  // Other methods with similar structure
}

interface SomeFieldEditCommand {
  String getSomeField();
}
```

**What I'm going to do**

```java
class N {

  // Other fields

  @Setter(Access.PACKAGE)
  private String someField;

  // Other fields
}

class SomeFieldEditCommand extends AbstractCommand {

  private final String someField;

  public void accept(N n) {
    // Some validations
    n.setSomeField(this.getSomeField()); // Does this code breaks encapsulation or it's normal behaviour?
  }
}
```

Comment: I would expect a `Command` to have an `execute()` method of some kind. Why is there an`editSomeField` method in another class? It's not "broken encapsulation", it's "tight coupling".

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks for reply. Yes it should has execute instead of accept. It would be more easy to read. I thought that accept is standard java functional interface with one arg and no return therefore there is accept. Yes, setters in commands causes tight coupling, this is what I want to keep away.

Answer (score 0):

> I feel that further it will have much more methods.

If avoiding proliferation of methods in domain types is your motivation for introducing commands, then be assured that defining methods in entities or aggregate roots is not only normal but is one of the DDD tenets (avoiding *anemic domain models*). Define intention-revealing public methods in the domain types; pass the values extracted from the DTO to them and do the property settings inside them; keep the property setters private.

> But it means that this commands will have the access to fields of N.

Command interface defines an `execute` method; a concrete command holds reference to a target type (`N` in your case) and encapsulates some operation on it in the `execute` method. So the concrete command obviously has coupling with the target class. Still if you want to introduce commands, you may call your domain entity methods from the command's `execute` method instead of setting properties.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You suggest to keep setting properties in domain class. I see two ways to implement that. The first is "Validators & Commands". That supposes to have a parallel hierarchy of classes that execute validation and a kind of classes with only data. Validators calls domain class method and passes the command. The second is to store data in Commands and domain class should get data from commands after command ended validation and called domain class with "this" argument. I was thinking about that. Both doesn't decrease number of methods significantly.

Comment: But the first introduces parallel hierarchy. Idk will that cause any problems in future but the fact is it. The second increases coupling. Have you any suggestions about how to improve any of the ways above?

Comment: In DDD, domain layer constructs (entities, aggregates, domain services, etc.) performs the core domain validations (e.g. whether an operation can be performed on an entity in its current state) in their methods or constructors even. They have the context for validation available to themselves. "Validators" should not be necessary for that. I'd recommend reserving validators for validations that require _external context_.

Comment: Also domain layer doesn't process commands themselves. They are intercepted a layer above; that layer calls the appropriate domain class methods with parameters parsed from the command.